Comenzando con Tailwind CSS pero no me funciona
Hola buenas tardes a todos estoy empezando a usar Tailwind Css para un proyecto, la cosa es que puede instalarlo sin problemas con una guia, cuando probe el ejemplo de "Hello World" me funcionaba todo, ya cuando empece a armar mi HTML para el proyecto comezaron los problemas
en el archivo input.css cuando quiero hacer cambios tipo darle estilo al body o los links
no los mostraba, despues sin hacer nada los mostro, pero hoy que quice continuar me esta pasando lo mismo agregue un hover a un link y no me hace el efecto trate de cambiar los valores que ya habia agregado como el border a otro color y tampoco lo hace alguien puede tener alguna idea cual es el error? Desde ya muchas gracias

Buenas, comparte el código de lo que has intentado y no te funciona. La guía de Tailwind es muy simple sobre como usarla. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Creo que ahi lo puede solucionar pero si te soy sincero lo unico que hice fue en la terminal un npm run watch como podria pasarte para saber si esta todo bien configurado

Copialo en la publicación, acá lo que se necesita es resolver un problema de código, por eso va siempre el código de donde se causa el problema. Lee [ask] y [mre] para entender mejor como responder.
